# How to INSERT INTO SELECT by considering IF EXISTS rules in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert, insert-update

In MySQL its possible to insert data retrieved from another table, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO
    `table2`
    (
        `table2_id`,
        `foo`
    )
SELECT
    `id`,
    `foo`
FROM
    `table1`
WHERE
    ...
;
```

On the other side it's also possible to define an `ON DUPLICATE` strategy:

- `INSERT IGNORE` statement
- `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause
- `REPLACE` statement

Now. How to combine both and insert data from another table, but handle duplications for every row? For `REPLACE` it's clear -- it works by just replacing `INSERT` by `REPLACE` in the query above. But **how to apply the `IGNORE` and `UPDATE` behaviour by `INSERT`ing data `SELECT`ed from another table?**

Comment: Is it just for mysql you need a MERGE operator . add what you don’t have and change what you have ...

Answer (score 0):

Such a combination is indeed possible:

**basic query**

```
INSERT INTO
    `table2`
    (
        `table2_id`,
        `foo`
    )
SELECT
    `id`,
    `foo`
FROM
    `table1`
WHERE
    ...
```

**`REPLACE`**

```
REPLACE INTO
    `table2`
    (
        `table2_id`,
        `foo`
    )
SELECT
    `id`,
    `foo`
FROM
    `table1`
WHERE
    ...
```

**`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`**

```
INSERT INTO
    `table2`
    (
        `table2_id`,
        `foo`
    )
SELECT
    `id`,
    `foo`
FROM
    `table1`
WHERE
    ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `foo` = `table1`.`foo`
;
```

**`INSERT IGNORE`**

```
INSERT IGNORE
    `table2`
    (
        `table2_id`,
        `foo`
    )
SELECT
    `id`,
    `foo`
FROM
    `table1`
WHERE
    ...
;
```